# When restore the package from Package.json through visual studio 2019 for Angular then below error is showing, I am using DOT NET not DOT NET CORE

Tags: angular

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! path C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\source\repos\Angular2Prj\Angular2Prj\node_modules.staging\normalize-package-data-ff026424\lib\fixer.js

npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\source\repos\Angular2Prj\Angular2Prj\node_modules.staging\normalize-package-data-ff026424\lib\fixer.js'

npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\source\repos\Angular2Prj\Angular2Prj\node_modules.staging\normalize-package-data-ff026424\lib\fixer.js']

npm ERR!   cause:

npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\source\repos\Angular2Prj\Angular2Prj\node_modules.staging\normalize-package-data-ff026424\lib\fixer.js'

npm ERR!      errno: -4048,

npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',

npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\source\repos\Angular2Prj\Angular2Prj\node_modules\.staging\normalize-package-data-ff026424\lib\fixer.js' },

npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\source\repos\Angular2Prj\Angular2Prj\node_modules\.staging\normalize-package-data-ff026424\lib\fixer.js\'',

npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\source\repos\Angular2Prj\Angular2Prj\node_modules\.staging\normalize-package-data-ff026424\lib\fixer.js',

npm ERR!   parent: 'Angular2Prj' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.

npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for connect@3.6.6 (sha1-Ce/2xVr3I24TcTWnJXSFi2eG9SQ=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

Comment: Delete ```node_modules``` then ```npm install```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far. Also, since you have an error, please include the full error traceback in the text of the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask